# Order of filters in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

How do I get a filter added as decorator in a controller to trigger AFTER a filter added in startup please?

I.e.
My Startup.cs looks like this:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add<MyErrorHandlingFilter>();
            });
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost()]
[SignResponseFilter]
public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] request)
{
  // does stuff and causes an exception(the MyErrorHandlingFilter.OnExceptionAsync() to be called)
}
```

My SignResponseFilter:
public class SignResponseFilter : TypeFilterAttribute
{

```
    public SignResponseFilter() : base(typeof(SignResponseFilterImplementation))
    {
    }
    private class SignResponseFilter: IAsyncResultFilter
    {
        private readonly ISign _signer;
        public SignResponseImplementation(ISign signer)
        {
            _signer= signer;
        }

        public async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            await next();

            var response = await ResponseBodyReader.ReadResponseBody(context.HttpContext.Response);

            var signature = await _signer.signIt(response);

            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("myheader", signature);
        }
    }
}
```

MyErrorHandlingerfilter:

```
public class MyErrorHandlingerfilter: ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IFormatter _formatter;
        public CustomErrorHandlerFilterAttribute(IFormatter fortmatter)
        {
            _formatter = fortmatter;
        }

        public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
        {
             _formatter.DoFormatting(); // does some formatting

            await base.OnExceptionAsync(context);
        }
```

My problem is that SignResponseFilter is skipped when an exception occurs.  MyErrorHandlingFilter does its formatting though. I would like it that SignResponse occurs on success and also, even when an exception occurs.

Comment: [`IAsyncAlwaysRunResultFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#ialwaysrunresultfilter-and-iasyncalwaysrunresultfilter) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following diagram shows how these filters interact in filter pipeline during request and response life cycle.

[image]

According your code, the SignResponseFilter is a Result filter, so, from above diagram, we can know that when the exception executed, it will trigger the Exception Filter first, not trigger the Result Filter. So, the SignResponse not occurs.

If you want to use other Filters with the Exception Filter, you could consider using the Action Filter.

More detail information, check [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#implementation)

Comment: Thanks. I struggle to understand this diagram to be honest.  It was not obvious (still isn't) that it skips Result on exception but you pointing out makes some sense of it for me.